# cant get datafile output to print the next line from the file, prints first line multiple times

Tags: python, csv

```
if option == 2:
        print("These are the lines of data from the data file:")
        datafile = open("K:/python compiler/datafile.dat","r")
        line = datafile.readline()
        field = line.split(",")
        custid = field[0]
        widgets = field[1]
        gidgets = field[2]
        doodads = field[3]
        count = 0
        while line != "":

            count += 1
            print("\n", count, " - Customer id:", field[0] , "\nWidgets     ordered:", field[1], "\nGidgets ordered:", field[2], "\nDoodads ordered:", field[3] , end = "")
            line = datafile.readline(line )
       datafile.close()
```

the last while statement seems to be the problem, just dont know why it wont advance to the next line

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign **field** in the **while** loop.

```
while line != "":
    count += 1
    print("\n", count, " - Customer id:", field[0] , "\nWidgets     ordered:", field[1], "\nGidgets ordered:", field[2], "\nDoodads ordered:", field[3] , end = "")
    line = datafile.readline()
    field = line.split(",")
```